# VBA send email in excel

Tags: time, copy, copy-paste

Part of my code copys info from one worksheet in Excell to another.  Every time I run this cood it gives me a run time error '1004' for the last line of code (activeSheet.Paste).  Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Sub CopyData()

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Sheets("sponsor & contributions 2012").Select
    Range("A1:K93").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("remaining payments").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
    Range("A1:K93").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simulating a user 'copy+paste', it's easier, quicker and more robust to set the value of your target range to that of your source range. e.g.

```
Public Sub Copy()
    Sheet2.Range("A1:K93").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:K93").Value
End Sub
```

Determining the cause of a 1004 error can be very difficult without being able to look over the spreadsheet, so I would definitely recommend the above approach